# Want to present modal view but how to make it take up screen partially?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I have two viewcontrollers. (See the attachment) Viewcontroller on the left is called "ViewController" and Modal viewController on the right is known as "draggableViewController". When I run this app, blue view object on the right will take over the first viewController. Blue view object on the Right Modal viewController should slide over on top of the first viewController, but I am presenting that view with no animation, so it will appear as if blue view has been resting on top of first ViewController.

What I want to achieve is to show only 1/3 of the blue view and I want it to rest on bottom 1/3 of the screen. I have no idea on how to set the position of blue view
to show it only on bottom 1/3 of the screen.

Here is my source code for each of viewControllers.

## 1: ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let newView = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "draggableViewController") as! draggableViewController
        newView.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overFullScreen
        self.present(newView, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

## 2: draggableViewController:

```
class draggableViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 300, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)

        let panGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panGestureRecognizerAction(_:)))

        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(panGestureRecognizer)
    }

    @objc func panGestureRecognizerAction(_ gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer){

        // 1. use these values to restrict the left and right sides so the orangeImageView won't go beyond these points
        let leftSideRestrction = self.view.frame.minX
        let rightSideRestriction = self.view.frame.maxX
        let topRestriction = 0

        // 2. use these values to redraw the orangeImageView's correct size in either Step 6 or Step 8 below
        let imageViewHeight = self.view.frame.size.height
        let imageViewWidth = self.view.frame.size.width

         if gestureRecognizer.state == .changed || gestureRecognizer.state == .began {

            let translation: CGPoint = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: self.view)

            gestureRecognizer.view!.center = CGPoint(x: gestureRecognizer.view!.center.x  + translation.x, y: gestureRecognizer.view!.center.y + translation.y)

            gestureRecognizer.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: self.view)     
            /*
             3.
             -get the the upper left hand corner of the imageView's X and Y origin to get the current location of the imageView as it's dragged across the screen.
             -you need the orangeImageView.frame.origin.x value to make sure it doesn't go beyond the left or right edges
             -you need the orangeImageView.frame.origin.y value to redraw it in Steps 6 and 8 at whatever Y position it's in when it hits either the left or right sides
             */
            var imageViewCurrentOrginXValue = self.view.frame.origin.x
            var imageViewCurrentOrginYValue = self.view.frame.origin.y

            print("origin x: \(imageViewCurrentOrginXValue)")
            print("origin y: \(imageViewCurrentOrginYValue)")

            // 4. get the right side of the orangeImageView. It's computed using the orangeImageView.frame.origin.x + orangeImageView.frame.size.width
            let imageViewRightEdgePosition = imageViewCurrentOrginXValue + imageViewWidth


            // 5. if the the orangeImageView.frame.origin.x touches the left edge of the screen or beyond it proceed to Step 6
            if imageViewCurrentOrginXValue <= leftSideRestrction {

                // 6. redraw the orangeImageView's frame with x: being the far left side of the screen and Y being where ever the current orangeImageView.frame.origin.y is currently positioned at
                if imageViewCurrentOrginYValue <= 0 {

                    // 6. redraw the orangeImageView's frame with x: being the far left side of the screen and Y being where ever the current orangeImageView.frame.origin.y is currently positioned at
                    imageViewCurrentOrginYValue = 0

                    self.view.frame = CGRect(x: leftSideRestrction, y: imageViewCurrentOrginYValue, width: imageViewWidth, height: imageViewHeight)    
                }

                if imageViewCurrentOrginYValue >= self.view.frame.height-200 {

                    // 6. redraw the orangeImageView's frame with x: being the far left side of the screen and Y being where ever the current orangeImageView.frame.origin.y is currently positioned at
                    imageViewCurrentOrginYValue = self.view.frame.height - 200

                    print(imageViewCurrentOrginYValue)

                    self.view.frame = CGRect(x: leftSideRestrction, y: imageViewCurrentOrginYValue, width: imageViewWidth, height: imageViewHeight)   
                }

                self.view.frame = CGRect(x: leftSideRestrction, y: imageViewCurrentOrginYValue, width: imageViewWidth, height: imageViewHeight)
            }

            // 7. if the the orangeImageView.frame.origin.x touches the right edge of the screen or beyond it proceed to Step 8
            if imageViewRightEdgePosition >= rightSideRestriction{

                // 8. redraw the orangeImageView's frame with x: being the rightSide of the screen - the orangeImageView's width and y: being where ever the current orangeImageView.frame.origin.y is currently positioned at
                if imageViewCurrentOrginYValue <= 0 {

                    // 6. redraw the orangeImageView's frame with x: being the far left side of the screen and Y being where ever the current orangeImageView.frame.origin.y is currently positioned at
                    imageViewCurrentOrginYValue = 0

                    self.view.frame = CGRect(x: leftSideRestrction, y: imageViewCurrentOrginYValue, width: imageViewWidth, height: imageViewHeight)
                }

                if imageViewCurrentOrginYValue >= self.view.frame.height - 200 {

                    // 6. redraw the orangeImageView's frame with x: being the far left side of the screen and Y being where ever the current orangeImageView.frame.origin.y is currently positioned at

                    imageViewCurrentOrginYValue = self.view.frame.height - 200

                    print(imageViewCurrentOrginYValue)

                    self.view.frame = CGRect(x: leftSideRestrction, y: imageViewCurrentOrginYValue, width: imageViewWidth, height: imageViewHeight)
                }

                self.view.frame = CGRect(x: rightSideRestriction - imageViewWidth, y: imageViewCurrentOrginYValue, width: imageViewWidth, height: imageViewHeight)
            }
    }

  }

}
```

[image: Viewcontroller on the left is called "ViewController" and viewController on the right is known as "draggableViewController"]

Where do I set the position of that blue view?

Comment: Do you think that your BlueViewController can be a UIView which slides 1/3 way to be visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is to set constraints in the blue view to be 1/3 the size of the main controller, and make the background transparent, or blurry so it shows as its sliding up only 1/3 the size. 
Steps to this, set a View inside the blue and use that view, and everything behind it to make it transparent.

Answer (score 0):

> Where do I set the position of that blue view

In a UIPresentationController subclass, when you do this properly as a custom transition animation.